# Mysql function used within a VIEW does not return the correct result.

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

I am facing a weird issue (i tried to look for previous answers but i could not find anything).
I created this function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CALCULATEDATE`(caller VARCHAR(4)) RETURNS date
BEGIN
DECLARE cur_day INT(2);
DECLARE cur_time INT(2);
DECLARE calculated_date DATE;

IF caller = 'HOME' THEN
    SELECT DAY(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@system_time_zone,'US/Pacific')) INTO cur_day; 
    SELECT HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@system_time_zone,'US/Pacific')) INTO cur_time; 
    /*Case homepage */
    IF cur_day = DAY(NOW()) THEN
        IF cur_time < 7 THEN
            /*return yesterdays date */
            SET calculated_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        ELSE
            /*return todays date */
            SET calculated_date = CURDATE();
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SET calculated_date = DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@system_time_zone,'US/Pacific'));
    END IF;
ELSE
    /*Case newsletter */

    /*return todays date */
    SET calculated_date = CURDATE();
END IF;

RETURN calculated_date;
END
```

Which returns a date (based on PST time comparison).

I am calling this function from a view:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `dd_vwfeatured` AS
    (SELECT 
        `doms`.`id` AS `id`,
        `doms`.`name` AS `name`

    FROM
        `myelements` `doms`
    WHERE
        `doms`.`id` IN (SELECT 
                `d`.`domainid`
            FROM
                (`daily_featured_picks` `d`
                LEFT JOIN `daily_featured` `f` ON ((`d`.`featuredid` = `f`.`id`)))
            WHERE
                (`f`.`date` = CALCULATEDATE('NEWS')))
    ORDER BY `doms`.`name`)
```

The function works perfectly if called from the mysql query, but within a view i get all records in return always.

Can you guys help?

Thanks,
DT

Comment: All domains are returned by the subquery, regardless of the date.

Comment: No, if i manually set a different date in the view it return different picks.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it (not sure why it does not worn in the view).
I changed approach and used a stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(IN p VARCHAR(4))
BEGIN
DECLARE p_tipo  DATE;

SELECT CALCULATEDATE(p) 
    INTO p_tipo;

SELECT 
        `doms`.`id` AS `id`,
        `doms`.`name` AS `name`,
        `doms`.`description` AS `description`,
        `doms`.`price` AS `price`
    FROM
        `myelements` `doms`
    WHERE
        `doms`.`id` IN (SELECT 
                `d`.`domainid`
            FROM
                (`daily_featured_picks` `d`
                LEFT JOIN `daily_featured` `f` ON ((`d`.`featuredid` = `f`.`id`)))
            WHERE
                (`f`.`date` = p_tipo))
    ORDER BY `doms`.`name`;

END
```